# RecordRTC | Can we save blob data without stopRecording

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, video-capture, recordrtc

I'm using RecordRTC and trying to save video after every 1 minute but for saving the video I have to call stopRecording().
For example:

```
function postFiles() {
            var blob = recorder.getBlob();
            // getting unique identifier for the file name
            var fileName = generateRandomString() + '.webm';

            var file = new File([blob], fileName, {
                type: 'video/webm'
            });

            xhr('/uploadFile', file, function(responseText) {
                    console.log(responseText);
            });

            if(mediaStream) mediaStream.stop();
        }

stopRecording(postFiles);
```

I wanted to save the video without stopping the recording.

Answer (score 4):

Relevant demo: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/simple-demos/ondataavailable.html

```
recorder = RecordRTC(camera, {
    recorderType: MediaStreamRecorder,
    mimeType: 'video/webm',
    timeSlice: 1000, // pass this parameter
    ondataavailable: function(blob) {
        invokeSaveAsDialog(blob);
    }
});
```

As you can see, I've passed two additional parameters:

1. `ondataavailable` callback function
2. `timeSlice` interval

`ondataavailable` will return blob after every specified interval.

Comment: I am sending this to node js server thru sockets. I am sending 'blob' there, and recieving Buffer on node js... how can I socket.broadcast.emit() from server, so someone can watch live the stream? How should I encode/decode it?

Comment: @Muaz Khan have tried the same approach but getting the first video chunk saved correctly and the remaining chunks are not saving properly. They do not even play at all. Is there any solution for it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67936072/recording-the-web-page-by-using-record-rtc-with-angular Anyone can help me on this.